# Problème MVC three.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, three.js

I have a threejs code that allows me to create a virtual tour, I want to implement an mvc method but for now I have some error that I can't solve.

Here is what I did

Scene.js

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { TweenLite } from '/gsap/src/all.js'
import { init } from '/client.js';
let scene;
class Scene {

    constructor(image, camera) {
        this.image = image
        this.points = []
        this.sprites = []
        this.scene = null
        this.camera = camera
    }

    //Création de la scène
    createScene(scene) {
        this.scene = scene
        const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(11, 32, 32)
        const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(this.image)
        texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping
        texture.repeat.x = -1
        texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: texture,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide
        })
        material.transparent = true

        this.sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
        this.scene.add(this.sphere)
        this.points.forEach(this.addTooltip.bind(this))


    }

    addPoint(point) {
        this.points.push(point)
    }

    //Création du tooltip
    addTooltip = function (point) {

        var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
        let spriteMap = loader.load('../photo/' + point.image, (texture) => {
            let spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
                map: spriteMap
            })
            let sprite = new THREE.Sprite(spriteMaterial)
            sprite.name = point.name;
            sprite.position.copy(point.position.clone().normalize().multiplyScalar(10));
            sprite.scale.multiplyScalar(2)
            this.scene.add(sprite);
            this.sprites.push(sprite);
            if (point.scene !== false) {
                sprite.onClick = () => {
                    this.destroy();
                        point.scene.destroy(scene);
                        point.scene.createScene(scene);
                        TweenLite.to(this.sphere.material, 1, {
                            opacity: 0,
                            onComplete: () => {
                                this.scene.remove(this.sphere)
                            }
                        })
                }
            } else {
                sprite.onClick = () => { }
            }
        })

    }

    //Destruction des tooltip/scene a chaque changement de scene
    destroy() {

        this.sprites.forEach((sprite) => {
            this.sprites.forEach((sprite) => {
                TweenLite.to(sprite.scale, 1, {
                    x: 0,
                    y: 0,
                    z: 0,
                    onComplete: () => {
                        this.scene.remove(sprite)
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    }

    //Apparition des nouveaux point de scene
    appear() {
        this.sprites.forEach((sprite) => {
            sprite.scale.set(0, 0, 0)
            TweenLite.to(sprite.scale, 1, {
                x: 1,
                y: 3,
                z: 3
            })
        })

    }

}

export default Scene;
```

Client.Js

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { OrbitControls } from './jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js'
import Scene from '/js/scene.js';



window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    init();
})

export function init() {
    const tooltip = document.querySelector('#tooltip')
    let renderer
    let scene;
    const container = document.body
    scene = new THREE.Scene()

    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100)
    camera.position.z = 2

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        canvas: document.querySelector('#world'),
    });
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

    const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
    controls.maxDistance = 3;
    controls.minDistance = 0.9;
    controls.rotateSpeed = -0.3
    controls.enableZoom = true
    controls.enablePan = false
    controls.autoRotate = true
    controls.autoRotateSpeed = 0.1
    controls.enableDamping = true;
    controls.dampingFactor = 0.3;
    camera.position.set(1, 0, 0)
    controls.update()
    let s = new Scene('photo/entre.jpg', camera)
    let s2 = new Scene('photo/entre.jpg', camera)

    s.addPoint({
        position: new THREE.Vector3(-10.468942480245712, -1.467960149500938, -2.8200827216367097),
        name: '',
        scene: s2,
        image: '/logo/hall.png'
    })

    s.createScene(scene)
    s.appear()

    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

    window.addEventListener(
        'resize',
        () => {
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
            render()
        },
        false
    )

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate)
        controls.update()
        render()
    }

    function render() {

        renderer.render(scene, camera)
    }

    animate()

    const rayCaster = new THREE.Raycaster()

    function onClick(e) {

        let mouse = new THREE.Vector2(
            (e.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1,
            -(e.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1

        )

        rayCaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera)
        let intersects = rayCaster.intersectObjects(scene.children)

        intersects.forEach(function (intersect) {
            if (intersect.object.type === 'Sprite') {

                intersect.object.onClick()
                if (spriteActive) {
                    tooltip.classList.remove('is-active')
                    spriteActive = false
                }
            }
        })

        intersects = rayCaster.intersectObject(s.sphere)
        if (intersects.length > 0) {
            console.log(intersects[0].point)

        }
        let intersectes = rayCaster.intersectObjects(scene.children)
        intersects.forEach(function (intersect) {
            if (intersectes[0].object.type == "Sprite") {
                gsap.to(camera.position, {
                    x: -intersectes[0].object.position.x,
                    y: 0,
                    z: -intersectes[0].object.position.z,
                    duration: 1.5,
                    ease: "power4.inOut",
                })
            }
        })


    }

    function onMouseMove(e) {
        let mouse = new THREE.Vector2(
            (e.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1,
            -(e.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1
        )
        rayCaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera)
        let foundSprite = false
        let intersects = rayCaster.intersectObjects(scene.children)
        intersects.forEach(function (intersect) {
            if (intersect.object.name != '') {
                let p = intersect.object.position.clone().project(camera)
                tooltip.style.top = ((-1 * p.y + 1) * window.innerHeight / 2) + 'px'
                tooltip.style.left = ((p.x + 1) * window.innerWidth / 2) + 'px'
                tooltip.classList.add('is-active')
                //Texte dans le tooltip
                foundSprite = true
            }
            if (foundSprite) {
                container.classList.add('hover')
                controls.autoRotate = false
            } else {
                container.classList.remove('hover')
                controls.autoRotate = true;
            }

        })

    }

    container.addEventListener('click', onClick)
    container.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove)


}
```

And here is the error I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')
    at Scene.createScene (scene.js:30:20)
    at sprite.onClick (scene.js:58:37)
    at client.js:94:34
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLBodyElement.onClick (client.js:91:20)
```

I've tried everything but no idea so far.
it seems to me that I can't get the scene variable which is in the init() or in the CreateScene method, I don't know
Thanks for your future help.

Answer (score 0):

You should read through the error, it gives you lots of info of where the error is happening:

at `Sprite.onClick`, you're calling `Scene.createScene`, where you're calling `.add()` on and undefined variable.

So, looking through your code, now you can pinpoint where it's happening:

```js
if (point.scene !== false) {
    sprite.onClick = () => {
        this.destroy();
        point.scene.destroy(scene);

        // 'scene' doesn't exist here, so it's undefined
        point.scene.createScene(scene);
```